# Create or join QBChatDialog if already exists

Tags: ios, dialog, quickblox

I am using quickblox latest version 2.6.6

Currently the QBChatDialogs are being created more than one time.

I just want something like it wont create a new group dialog every time.

And while creating it should check if a QBChatdialog already exists then it should return it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are chatting 1to1 there will be always one dialog (QBChatDialogTypePrivate).
If you are creating group dialog, of course it will be new dialog every time. You can create a custom object and set it to QBChatDialog data to manage dialogs in a way you want them to be. Here is guide on how to do it: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Custom_parameters